# removing the last marker added to map

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am working on an app that I have to mark many places on the map and I want to remove the last added marker to the map. the method I am using is clearing all the markers

this is the  method I am using to add marker

```
void _setMarkers(LatLng point) {
    final String markerIdVal = 'marker_id_$_markerIdCounter';
    _markerIdCounter++;
    setState(() {
      print(
          'Marker | Latitude: ${point.latitude}  Longitude: ${point.longitude}');
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(markerIdVal),
          position: point,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

and this is the undopoint methode

```
Widget _undomarker() {
    return FloatingActionButton.extended(
      onPressed: () {
        //Remove marker
        setState(() {
          _markers.clear();
        });
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.undo),
      label: Text('Undo point'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Widget _undomarker() {
return FloatingActionButton.extended(
  onPressed: () {
    //Removes the last marker only
    setState(() {
      _markers.remove( _markers.last );
    });
  },
  icon: Icon(Icons.undo),
  label: Text('Undo point'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
);
```

Comment: _markers isn't a list srry for not mention it.         Set<Marker> _markers = HashSet<Marker>();

Comment: and I didn't know how to store the markers in a list.

Comment: @HamzaLaabidi i have updated the code.. check